# Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException Received 0 bytes from stream in MVC under Mono

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ubuntu, ssl, mono

I have an ASP.NET MVC application running on Mono 4.0.5 under Ubuntu 15.04. The application works as expected while the internet access is available, but if the OS is restarted on a network without internet connection, I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried updating machine and user certificate stores without any success using "mozroots --import --sync --machine".

It should be noted that this error only occurs on the Login page (using Forms Authentication with MySQL provider with "requireSSL" set to "false").

I don't use SSL on any of my pages and don't have it enabled/configured in Apache/Mod_Mono configuration. The LoginController doesn't make any (e.g. HTTPS) requests either.

Also, I've tried running the application through XSP4, which produced exactly the same behavior.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting logs, I've noticed that the system date was set to to 01/01/1970. After updating the date and restarting Apache, everything worked. I guess in my case the NTP was updating the date/time on boot every time and without internet connection was falling back to Unix epoch.

Comment: glad you fixed your problem; that being said, I recommend you update your OS, e.g. to ubuntu 16.04 which is LTS (more chances to have fixes) and newer version of mono